# Modal within a table in MDBootstrap for reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-material-design, mdbreact

I am fairly new to reactjs and material design bootstrap. I am trying to populate a set of data on to a table using a mock json file.
I did manage to find some degree of success in that. I wanted to incorporate a modal in the table row. such that when I click the row a modal popups.

I will post the code I have used. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//TablePage.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MDBDataTable } from "mdbreact";
import testdata from "../../data.js";

class TablePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        columns: [
          {
            label: "test ID",
            field: "testID",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            label: "test Entity",
            field: "testEntity",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            label: "test Entity Key",
            field: "testEntityKey",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            label: "test Business Date",
            field: "testBusinessDate",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 100
          },
          {
            label: "test created Date",
            field: "testcreatedDate",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 100
          },
          {
            label: "testScore",
            field: "test Score",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            label: "test Score Normalised",
            field: "testScoreNormalised",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          ,
          {
            label: "testUnitIdentifier",
            field: "test Unit Identifier",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            label: "testOwnerIdentifier",
            field: "testOwner Identifier",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            label: "testState",
            field: "test State",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            label: "edit",
            field: "Edit",
            sort: "asc",
            width: 50
          }
        ],
        rows: testdata
      }
    };

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <MDBDataTable btn striped bordered hover data={this.state.data}>
        test
      </MDBDataTable>
    );
  }
}

export default TablePage;
```

This is the mock data file I have tried to use.

```
//data.js
const data = [
    {
        testID: 938932,
        testEntity: "employee",
        testEntityKey: 1527003,
        testBusinessDate: "6/14/2017",
        testcreatedDate: "8/7/2017",
        testScore: 115,
        testScoreNormalised: "100",
        testUnitIdentifier: "",
        testownerIdentifier: "938932",
        testState: "inprogress"
    },
    {
        testID: 903576,
        testEntity: "employee",
        testEntityKey: 1593873,
        testBusinessDate: "6/5/2017",
        testcreatedDate: "1/17/2018",
        testScore: 175,
        testScoreNormalised: "100",
        testUnitIdentifier: "",
        testownerIdentifier: "903576",
        testState: "onhold"
    },
    {
        testID: 947830,
        testEntity: "employee",
        testEntityKey: 1735438,
        testBusinessDate: "8/16/2017",
        testcreatedDate: "10/14/2017",
        testScore: 139,
        testScoreNormalised: "100",
        businessUnitIdentifier: "",
        testownerIdentifier: "947830",
        testState: "inprogress"
    },
    {
        testID: 952479,
        testEntity: "employee",
        testEntityKey: 1305158,
        testBusinessDate: "1/14/2018",
        testcreatedDate: "2/3/2018",
        testScore: 160,
        testScoreNormalised: "100",
        testUnitIdentifier: "",
        testownerIdentifier: "952479",
        testState: "ready"
    },
    {
        testID: 927366,
        testEntity: "employee",
        testEntityKey: 1645384,
        testBusinessDate: "8/20/2017",
        testcreatedDate: "3/18/2018",
        testScore: 123,
        testScoreNormalised: "100",
        testUnitIdentifier: "",
        testownerIdentifier: "927366",
        testState: "onhold"
    }]
```

I will post a picture as well

[Table snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5os70.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to know how to add a button to open a modal window in the edit cell. This can be done easily by adding the component to the edit field in your data.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ModalPage from './ModalPage';

export default [
  {
    testID: 938932,
    testEntity: "employee",
    testEntityKey: 1527003,
    testBusinessDate: "6/14/2017",
    testcreatedDate: "8/7/2017",
    testScore: 115,
    testScoreNormalised: "100",
    testUnitIdentifier: "",
    testownerIdentifier: "938932",
    testState: "inprogress",
    edit: <ModalPage />
  },
  {
    testID: 927366,
    testEntity: "employee",
    testEntityKey: 1645384,
    testBusinessDate: "8/20/2017",
    testcreatedDate: "3/18/2018",
    testScore: 123,
    testScoreNormalised: "100",
    testUnitIdentifier: "",
    testownerIdentifier: "927366",
    testState: "onhold",
    edit: <ModalPage />
  }
];
```

The ModalPage component I've used here is the modal page example component from the mdb [docs](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/modals/basic/). You can reference the example I've made on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-92kvrq).

More info on how to customize your data table to include different controls you can find [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/additional/).

Comment: Yes it did solve my problem ... I  ran into another problem .. which i am trying to sort out now :)